# R: Running out of memory using table function to find the most frequent character in a big matrix

Tags: r

I would like to find out the most frequent character in a big-data matrix .I m using table function to do this.When i got this character i would like to delete the rows that there is located and continue with the same procedure with the remaining rows .For example "

```
 m1<-matrix(c("a","b","a","c","b","a","a","a","c","c","b","a","a","b","b","c","b","a"),nrow=9,ncol=2,byrow = TRUE)
 temp <- table(as.vector(m1))
 t1<-names(temp)[temp == max(temp)]
 m2<-m1[rowSums(m1== t1[1]) == 0, ]
 temp2 <- table(as.vector(m2))
 t2<-names(temp2)[temp2 == max(temp2)]
```

When im using a big data matrix (i combine many big txt files) my system goes out of memory with the table function .
Is there any way (package or function) to solve this ?

Unfortunately im not familiar wiith any package  that requires special code .

i m using windows 7 64-bit 16gb ram

Comment: `data.table` package works pretty fast with large tables, not sure about memory

Comment: Thanks @ AndriyTkach for the reply .Unfortunately im not familiar wiith any package  that requires special code ( i wiil add this information to my post) .In your suggestion , after loading the package i will only replace "table" with "data.table" ?

Comment: Can you have the characters on a file and read it line by line? That way, you avoid the need to store all characters at once.

Comment: @gvrocha ,if i understand your suggestion , I believe for export the most frequent character is necessary to store all of them in one table .

Comment: @AndriyTkach  :  i just  tested the data.table package ,i replace the "table" function and "t1" gives : Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables..............?

Comment: @pshls not exactly, you should transform your matrix in data.table: `temp <- as.data.table(m1)`